# How to parse last value from CSV every five minutes?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I need to run script to parse the value from csv every five minutes but should not parse the all the values all the time it should be from the last point.

Comment: Why every 5 minutes ? What about parsing it live ? Like using tail -f ? Maybe a kind of `tail -f FILE | cut -d',' -f FIELD_NUMBER | logtop` ?

Comment: You need to remember the seek position and restore it before parsing the modified file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really just putting some flesh on @hek2mgl's suggestion and implementing it for you.

I store the last known length of the logfile in another file called `lastlength`.

```
#!/bin/bash

LOGFILE=somelog.csv
LASTLEN=lastlength

# Pre-set seek to start of file...
seek=0

# ... but overwrite if there was a previously seen value
[ -f lastlength ] && seek=$(cat lastlength)

echo DEBUG: Starting from offset $seek

# Update last seen length into file - parameters to "stat" will differ on Linux
stat -f "%Dz" "$LOGFILE" > "$LASTLEN"

# Get last line of file starting from previous position
dd if="$LOGFILE" bs=$seek skip=1 2> /dev/null | tail -1
```

I am using OSX, so if you are using Linux, the parameters to the `stat` command in the second to last line will be different, probably

```
stat -c%s "$LOGFILE"  > "$LASTLEN"
```

I'll leave you to put it into your *crontab* so it gets called every 5 minutes.

Comment: This works fine but we need to put the column name along with the output as the column name is a random name. how we can achieve this ?

Comment: I noticed that it parse the value from the last one only not from the starting point where it was left also as I mentioned in last comment that it is also needed to parse the column/heading name along with this output. Could you please let me know what could be the command ?

Comment: OK so now after removing the tail -1 it works but still need to know how to parse the column name along with this output ?

Comment: Add a `head -1 YourFile` just before the final `dd`

Comment: i added like this but didn't work.    head -1 dd if="$LOGFILE" bs=$seek skip=1 2> /dev/null

Comment: Add `head -1 "$LOGFILE"` on a new line on its own above the line starting `dd ...`